# Commas around 'Too'

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends

I see it both ways with a comma before a sentence-ending 'too' and a comma on each side of 'too' when it's the second word in a sentence. Are these commas really needed? Would you personally use them? I think we could leave these sentences as is without the commas. Do you concur?

1. *He too makes a few unforced errors, and we're at deuce.*  (Comma  needed before and after 'too'?)
2. *She too admired his looks and his courtliness.* (Comma needed before and after 'too'?)
3. *She admired his looks and his courtliness too.* (Comma before 'too'?)
4. *He wanted to go too but decided not to.* (Comma before and after 'too'?)
5. *He wanted to go too, but he decided not to.*(Comma before and after 'too'?)
6. *He too puts commas around 'too'.* (Comma before and after the first 'too'?)

Headline:
*Obama Says He Too Is a Poverty Fighter In D.C., He Offers Contrast With Edwards* (Comma before and after 'too'?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these sentences need the suggested commas, and in some of them it would even confuse the meaning of the sentence. The most times you only need a comma are to:

1. Separate clauses (not all of the time)
2. Separate infinitive phrases at the beginning of a sentence from the rest of the sentence
3. Separate items of a list

Some of your sentences have one of a couple of exceptions to this rule of thumb, and one or both of you suggested commas are still grammatically correct. That being said, don't get comma-happy. When in doubt, leave the comma out. Take a look at this page and its many links for all the info you need on comma usage: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm

Comment: It's a good article. It doesn't touch upon what some have called the 'non-grammatical' usage (yes, some are going to say that 'punctuation isn't grammar', but it _does_ usually show what constructions are being used). eg [One Woman Shop](http://onewomanshop.com/author/ashley-brooks/)
"Commas: Use commas to create a pause if your breath units are getting too long."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A fair point, but from a purist perspective the reader puts in the pauses, not the writer. I  think of the writer's job as being to create a readable, sensible work, and the reader's job as being to make it sound good.

Comment: So you prefer picture books?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Naturally. My favorite is the picture book version of *Of Mice and Men*. The characterization of Lennie is simply exquisite, to the imaginative and tasteful reader. ;)

Comment: For those preferring reading books, [here](http://www.ucalgary.ca/uofc/eduweb/grammar/course/punctuation/3_4j.htm) is a source advocating a more reader-friendly approach:

**Using Commas to Prevent Misunderstanding**
Sometimes you must use a comma to make the reader pause in the appropriate place in the sentence in order to prevent misreading.
Becoming a good writer means developing an awareness of how your sentences will sound to the reader. Reading your work aloud, to yourself or to a friend, is a good way to identify the places in the sentence where pauses--or commas--are needed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Although I don't agree with you, this is still a perfectly valid link to post. If you want the maximum possible number of people to read it, post it as a comment to the question, not my answer. Unless this was intended to be a barb aimed at me more than it was intended to be helpful to anyone...

Comment: I'm adding it to make the most comprehensive single article on comma usage I've seen (your link) even more so. Admittedly, the 'non-grammatical' usages are not as generally accepted.