# When to use a comma before 'because', 'too', or 'and'

Tags: commas

> My camera is pink, and my mobile phone is black.

Is it right? And why yes or why not?

Or:

> My camera is small. my phone is small, too.

Are these commas correct?

When can I find the answers? Is there any grammar book, which can explain it to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct:

> My camera is pink, and my mobile phone is black.

These are two independent clauses, joined by a comma and the word *and*. This is the textbook example of how to correctly join two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction.

By contrast:

> My camera is small. my phone is small, too.

This is incorrect. You finished the first sentence (because it ended with a period) but then started the second sentence with a lowercase letter. If you want to join these two sentences (independent clauses) into a single sentence without using a coordinating conjunction (e.g. *and*), you can use a semicolon:

> My camera is small; my phone is small, too.
>
> My camera is pink; my mobile phone is black.

For comma usage rules, I would start with a search engine and the web. Here's a place to start: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

For long term learning and use, I would pick up a proper writer's guide, such as *The Holt Handbook*, *The Chicago Manual or Style*, or *The Writer's Reference*. (These aren't endorsements of these specific books, but rather examples of what I mean when I say a *writer's guide*.)

Comment: Thank you all. In the latter sentence I was thinking if it's correct to put comma before 'too'

Comment: I think it's fine, but the comma around "too" is highly subjective. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155017/commas-around-too for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

*Either*, *anyway*, and *too* are three of the most common words in that class of sentence closers. I struggled for weeks with it. Somebody had actually gone through *The New York Times* and catalogued the percentages. Closing with "anyway" was preceded by a comma 90% of the time, "too" 80% of the time, and "either" 30% of the time. Say your sentence out loud with and without the comma. What sounds more natural? "Too" should be preceded by a comma in the example "I love you, too" because of the potential for ambiguity between *two* and *too* at first glance.

Answer (score -1):

The comma is not necessary in your sentence. The "and" separates the two clauses without it. These links may help:

http://www.grammarly.com/blog/2015/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

http://www.buzzfeed.com/adamdavis/the-oxford-comma-is-extremely-important-and-everyone-should#.hrE3XvkKKg

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-commas-in-a-series.html

Comment: These examples speak to the use of the comma in a series. However, the OP question is about joining two independent clauses, so different rules apply.